# Return or modify .json file in NancyFX

Tags: c#, asp.net, nancy

I am trying to build a simple API with NancyFX, hosted with ASP.NET. When http://myapp/api/get is called, it should return some JSON which is stored in a file called "data.json", which is stored on the root level along with the main module. Also, http://myapp/api/set should set the contents of the JSON file.

My initial approach was this:

```
Get["/api/get"] = _ =>
{
  string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\data.json");
  object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
  return jsonObject;
}

Post["/api/set"] = parameters =>
{
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\data.json", json);
  return HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

However, the program can't find the file in runtime. After reading some answers in here, i tried doing the following (which didn't work either):

```
Get["/api/get"] = _ =>
{
  return new GenericFileResponse(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\sitefiles\data.json", "application/json");
}
```

The answers i found were from 2011, so i suspect that's why they don't work. What is the updated way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

After working a bit more, i have found a solution. You have to make a class model representing the data you are going to recieve, in this case the model is called InfoModel. Then i coded the Get and Post as such:

```
Get["/api/get"] = _ =>
{
  DefaultRootPathProvider pathProvider = new DefaultRootPathProvider();
  return new GenericFileResponse(pathProvider.GetRootPath() + "data.json", "application/json");
};

Post["/api/set"] = parameters =>
{
  DefaultRootPathProvider pathProvider = new DefaultRootPathProvider();
  var model = this.Bind<InfoModel>();
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
  File.WriteAllText(pathProvider.GetRootPath() + "data.json", json);
  return HttpStatusCode.OK;
};
```